# What is the control chip name of a MG90S servo motor?

Tags: servo

I'm learning about servos, and was wondering about the control chip name of MG90S.

I do not have the possibility to open one at the moment. It seems that this information is not easy to find, in comparison to the other parameters of these servos.

Is the chip a standard one in these servos?

[Here is a link I have found](https://www.towerpro.com.tw/product/mg90s-3/).

Comment: Please link the data sheet for the device.

Comment: Tear one down and see.. But apparently there are many counterfeits.

Comment: it may be a control and driver in one IC ... it would make sense for it to be a custom die

Comment: You can just study OpenServo if you want to see how a digital servo can work.

Answer (score 1):

The [Towerpro MG90S](https://vorpalrobotics.com/wiki/index.php/Tower_Pro_MG90S_Vs._Clones) is a *digital* servo. I can't find any images online that are clear enough to make out the part numbers, only that it has an 8 pin SOIC chip on one side of the PCB.

A digital servo usually has a small general purpose [microcontroller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcontroller) connected to a MOSFET bridge (which could be 4 individual MOSFETs, or one or two ICs with MOSFETs in them).

Answer (score -1):

My search effort came up with the M51660L IC with some discrete parts and 2 BJTs.

There may also be an alternate with AA prefix to the Mitsubishi part above.

Here is a full description link.

https://sound-au.com/articles/servos.htm

Comment: Unlikely. The M51660L is for analog servos, the MG90S is a digital servo.